# Problem passing down function as a prop in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, web-applications, functional-programming

```
class ReturnTempPassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props));

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { /* change code below this line */ }
            <p>Your temporary password is: <strong>{}</strong></p>
            { /* change code above this line */ }
        </div>
    );
  }
};

class ResetPassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pwdGen = this.pwdGen.bind(this);
  }

  // returns a random string as password
  pwdGen(m){
    var m = m || 9, str="",  r = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';;
    for(var i=0; i<m; i++) {
      str+= r.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*r.length));
    }
    return str;
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h2>Reset Password</h2>
          <h3>We've generated a new temporary password for you.</h3>
          <h3>Please reset this password from your account settings ASAP.</h3>
          { /* change code below this line */ }
          <ReturnTempPassword data={"data"} pass={this.pwdGen} /> 
          { /* change code above this line */ } 
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I'm sending down a function as a `prop` and want to access it in the child component **`ReturnTempPassword`**. But `data` is available as prop but not `pass`. Not sure what am i doing wrong?

FYI, this is a **freecodecamp** task, which I'm trying to solve in my own way.
Link to task is [here](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/react/access-props-using-this-props):

Please help me to correct the mistake.

Comment: I can provide the solution but I don't know how convenient that would be?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. The `JSON.stringify(this.props)` will not display the callback functions in the `props` because function is not an JSON value http://json.org/value.gif. Just try to implement the callback function where ever you want using `this.props.pass()` will work.

Comment: **@Kumar** Thanks for pointing that buddy. THis is good information for me.

Answer (score 0):

you do everything right
Add a call your function

```
class ReturnTempPassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props));

}

 render() {
return (
    <div>
        { /* change code below this line */ }
        <p>Your temporary password is: <strong>{this.props.pass(5)}</strong></p>
        { /* change code above this line */ }
    </div>
);
 }
 };

class ResetPassword extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
}

 // returns a random string as password
  pwdGen(m){
var m = m || 9, str="",  r = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';;
for(var i=0; i<m; i++) {
  str+= r.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*r.length));
}
return str;
}
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h2>Reset Password</h2>
      <h3>We've generated a new temporary password for you.</h3>
      <h3>Please reset this password from your account settings ASAP.</h3>
      { /* change code below this line */ }
      <ReturnTempPassword data={"data"} pass={this.pwdGen} /> 
      { /* change code above this line */ } 
    </div>
  );
}
```

};

And this code this.pwdGen = this.pwdGen.bind(this); are not needed

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. I tried checking with bind statement and it works with that as well. 
Can you please tell me why `bind` is not needed??

Comment: @VigneshSharma You only need to bind `this` to a method if you plan on using `this` within the method, for example: `this.setState()`. By binding `this`, it refers to the class and it's properties/methods: `ResetPassword`. Your function does not utilize `this`, therefore you don't need to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Since other people have provided solutions I can provide mine :)

In the task actually, they don't want you to create a random password text. They just want you to pass a "text" as a prop, named `tempPassword`. You want to use a function here. This is OK but I don't if it passes the test.

You can use this function in two ways.

1. You can pass it as a prop to the child.
2. You can use it directly in the parent.

Is there any specific reason you want to use in the child? I think, no.

So you can use it in the parent like:

```
<ReturnTempPassword pass={this.pwdGen()} />
```

and in the child:

```
<p>Your temporary password is: <strong>{this.props.pass}</strong></p>
```

As you can see since you can do it without passing your function to your child component. Also, you don't need to bind the function since it is not using `this` here, also it is not being called with a callback. It just a simple method and also can be totally separate from your class.

I've provided an example below like that. You don't need to pass the function as a prop here. In this way, you can use it anywhere. For example, you can put this function in a file then export it. When you need it, you can import it anywhere easily. This function doesn't need to belong to the class itself.

But, if you want to pass it as a prop, @mariamelior's answer shows how you can do this.

```js
// returns a random string as password
function pwdGen(m) {
  var m = m || 9,
    str = "",
    r = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    str += r.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length));
  }
  return str;
}

class ReturnTempPassword extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* change code below this line */}
        <p>
          Your temporary password is: <strong>{this.props.pass}</strong>
        </p>
        {/* change code above this line */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ResetPassword extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Reset Password</h2>
        <h3>We've generated a new temporary password for you.</h3>
        <h3>Please reset this password from your account settings ASAP.</h3>
        {/* change code below this line */}
        <ReturnTempPassword data={"data"} pass={pwdGen()} />
        {/* change code above this line */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ResetPassword />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. But, i really wanted to pass it down to the child comp as a prop. No specific reason, but want to do it that way :)

Comment: There are times you do that and there are times you don't. This is the one you don't :) I know you are just testing it, playing with React but when you learn something then learn the right way.Your function is not related to your Child, actually,it is not related to your Parent,too. It is just a simple function.So,passing it as a prop here does not mean anything.You've asked one of the answer's comment why bind is not needed. I've tried to explain it in my answer but this is one of the reasons why it should not be a prop :) You will use functions as a prop to your child,but not like this one.

Comment: okay, thanks.
How do you suggest I control the length of the password from the child component? 
My thoughts were grab the number from text input element in child component and then pass it as an argument when calling the function using prop.

Comment: You are welcome. Try to not ask multiple questions in one post. Accept one of the answers here, then ask another question about this problem and add the code what you have tried up to now to your question.